# Image Similarity Detection using Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm currently trying to make a tool to help me "clean" image datasets. What I want is this tool to be able to detect images that don't belong to the correct category. For example if I'm making a dataset of photos of airplanes but somehow got one car photo in there I want it to detect it being in the wrong category.

So far my approach was to try and create a model that can detect if 2 images are similar or not.
To do so I decided to feed a convolutional network with pairs of photos, some from the same category which I labeled as 1s and others from different categories which I labeled as 0s.

Here's some examples:

[cat_photo_1, cat_photo_2] --> 1

[cat_photo_1, airplane_photo_1] --> 0

[airplane_photo_1, airplane_photo_2] --> 1

I realized that I wasn't going to be able to use Keras Conv2D and MaxPooling2D layers since my input shape is (2, 150, 150, 3). So I decided to simply use the 3D ones hoping it would do the trick.

So I first tried building my network using this architecture:

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv3D(32, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(2, 150, 150, 3)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling3D((2, 2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv3D(64, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling3D((2, 2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv3D(64, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

But I got multiple errors about the kernel and pool size that I quite didn't understand so I simply tried changing the values and managed to make it work with these values:

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv3D(32, (2, 3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(2, 150, 150, 3)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling3D((1, 2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv3D(64, (1, 3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling3D((1, 2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv3D(64, (1, 3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

So my question is why did this work like this and is this a good approach to my problem?

Comment: Why can’t you use an image classification model two times (on each image) and compare the classes?

Comment: Yeah I thought about this method as a last resort solution but I first wanted to see if it was possible to directly train a model for it to recognize similarities between images.

Answer (score 0):

the approach which you are using may not suite your problem statement.
The best idea would be using **Triplet loss** as your loss function.
Paper like facenet use this loss function to compare the faces..
But you can use your images.

Comment: So I would feed the network with samples of 3 images (input, positive, negative) and use the Triplet Loss function? But what do I use for the labels?

Comment: 1 :if input and positive image is of same category, 0: if input and positive are of different category....